# Access - Uploading with multiple title rows

Tags: ms-access, upload

I am working to create a database. I have excel spreadsheets that will be uploaded which have two rows of titles: the first being the parameter and the second being units. I am new to access and all I know about uploading into it is using the import>excel command. When I try to upload one of these spreadsheets, access crashes (I assume because it's trying to interpret different types of data in a single column). How do I designate this second row as units and not data values?

Comment: You can't import two rows of headers. The only way to deal with the two rows is to use VBA to open the Excel file and deal with it (i.e. save the second row, delete from sheet, do import saying you have headers, then insert the row back in.   See these links: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1556448     or     https://superuser.com/questions/62758/multi-row-headers-and-excel-2007-sort-filtering

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I needed